# MySQL - Must be caught or declared to be thrown

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have built this class up from various post as good as i could.

I am trying to get a list of usernames from a MySQL database.

Here is the method retrieving them:

```
public ArrayList<String> LoadUsers() throws SQLException {
    ArrayList<String> players = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        Connection conn = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            conn = getConnection();
            Statement s = conn.createStatement ();
            s.executeQuery ("SELECT * FROM NFT_users");
            rs = s.getResultSet ();

            while(rs.next ()){
                players.add(rs.getString("name"));
            }
            rs.close ();
            s.close ();
        }

        catch (SQLException ex) { 
            System.out.println(ex.toString()); 
        }

        finally { 
            try { 
                if (conn != null) conn.close(); 
            } 

            catch (SQLException ex) { 
                System.out.println("On close: " + ex.toString()); 
            } 
        }
    } 

    catch(Exception ex) { 
        //trace(ex); 
    }

    return players;
}
```

And this is the code in my mainclass which retrieves it from the method:

```
    ArrayList<String> players = database.LoadUsers();
```

However, i get the error *Must be caught or declared to be thrown*. What do i do wrong?

Comment: Since you're surrounding your `LoadUsers()` method with `try-catch` you don't need to throw the exception. You're handling the exception inside your method. Don't throw the exception or remove the global `try-catch`.

Comment: I have not written much of this myself. And i am not familiar with try-catches yet, unfortunately. Perhaps you could post some code, that'd make it easier for me to understand. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method: -

```
public ArrayList<String> LoadUsers() throws SQLException {
```

has declared an `SQLException` in it's throws clause. So, from whichever method you call this method from, you would either need to enclose the `invocation` in a `try-catch` block to handle this exception, or declare this exception in the throws clause of that method also.

So, suppose you are calling your method from a method `caller()`.

**So, you have two options: -**

1. Declare exception in `throws` clause of `caller`: -

   ```
   public void caller() throws SQLException {
        ArrayList<String> players = database.LoadUsers();
   }
   ```
2. Enclose the method invocation in a try-catch. In this case, remember to declare your `list` outside the block first:

   ```
   public void caller() {
        ArrayList<String> players = null;
        try {
             players = database.LoadUsers();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
   ```

**Note** that, if you are using the first option, then you will again face same problem in the method that called `caller`. There also you would have to follow this thing.

In general, an exception raised inside a method is - either handled there using try-catch block, or is propagated up the stack trace to the immediate caller method, **but not both**. You are doing both in your method. You are handling the exception, and have declared it to be thrown in the `throws` clause too. You should never do that.

Comment: I'm very new at Java, so i would really love some actual code examples. I'm lost :-)

Comment: @PatrickReck.. There you go. I just added example for both options.

Comment: one additional note - as currently defined, the LoadUsers method does not actually ever throw a SQLException - they are always caught, logged, and not re-thrown. This is actually a well-known anti-pattern. There's probably no need to catch the exceptions in this method - you could just let the caller deal with them. Or...catch and log them, but remove the 'throws' declaration from the method. But not both.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek.. Yeah that's a good catch. Didn't notice this thing. But it would certainly be useful for OP.

Comment: Thank you for your time, Rohit.
I've tried to implement your solution, but it gives me a nullpointer at the players = database.LoadUsers(); line. (Used option 2)

@GreyBeardedGeek, how would i implement this?

Comment: @PatrickReck.. That's probably because your `database` is `null`. Please check that before invoking the method.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
try{
   ArrayList<String> players = database.LoadUsers();
}catch(SQLException e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

This is because your loadUsers method is throwing an exception. So, wherever you will call this method you need to surround it with try catch

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a previous comment, it's not a good idea to declare that the LoadUsers method throws an exception, and then to never throw it. This raises the expectation that the caller should be prepared to handle the exception, and indeed, the compiler will demand that the caller either surround the call with a try/catch block, or declare that it throws the exception.

So, there are (at least) three options.
The first is to have the LoadUsers method actually throw the exception, like this:

```
public ArrayList<String> LoadUsers() throws SQLException {
    ArrayList<String> players = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        Connection conn = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            conn = getConnection();
            Statement s = conn.createStatement ();
            s.executeQuery ("SELECT * FROM NFT_users");
            rs = s.getResultSet ();

            while(rs.next ()){
                players.add(rs.getString("name"));
            }
            rs.close ();
            s.close ();
        } finally { 
            try { 
                if (conn != null) conn.close(); 
            } catch (SQLException ex) { 
                // eat the exception - we can't do anything about it here 
            } 
        }
    } 

    return players;
}
```

and in the caller:

```
public void processPlayers() {
   try{
       ArrayList<String> players = database.LoadUsers();
      // do something with the players

   } catch(SQLException ex){

     ex.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

The second option uses the same LoadUsers() method, but doesn't catch the exception in the caller either - it passes it on to *its* caller:

```
public void processPlayers() throws SQLException {
      ArrayList<String> players = database.LoadUsers();
      // do something with the players
}
```

The third option is to catch the exception in the LoadUsers method, and not in the caller.
The problem here is that the caller won't know that there was problem - it will just get an empty list:

```
public ArrayList<String> LoadUsers() throws SQLException {
    ArrayList<String> players = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        Connection conn = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            conn = getConnection();
            Statement s = conn.createStatement ();
            s.executeQuery ("SELECT * FROM NFT_users");
            rs = s.getResultSet ();

            while(rs.next ()){
                players.add(rs.getString("name"));
            }
            rs.close ();
            s.close ();
        } catch(SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(); // but the caller won't know...
        }
          finally { 
            try { 
                if (conn != null) conn.close(); 
            } catch (SQLException ex) { 
                // eat the exception - we can't do anything about it here 
            } 
        }
    } 

    return players;
}
```

and

```
public void processPlayers() throws SQLException {
      ArrayList<String> players = database.LoadUsers(); // an empty list if something went wrong
      // do something with the players
}
```

This last option is not recommended.